# `expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token` inside a ternary operator

Tags: c

Inside the `call` function definition, I attempt to retrieve the variadic arguments passed to it in a loop using a ternary operator. The compilation stops with an `expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘(’ token` error.

```
#define ARG_N 3

char *args_types[ARG_N] = {"int", "float", "char"};

void call(...) {
  va_list args;
  void *args_values[ARG_N];
  va_start(args, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < ARG_N; ++i) {
    char *arg;
    arg = args_types[i];
    args_values[i] = (void *)va_arg(args, (strcmp(arg, "int") ? int : strcmp(arg, "float") ? float : char));
  }
  va_end(args);
}

int main(void) {
  call(6, 55.33, 'c');
  return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, this error occurs when a structure is used uninitialized. What does it mean in this context?

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mre]?

Comment: I try, but it's hard when I'm not sure which part affects the error.

Comment: `expression ? type : type` is not valid C syntax.

Comment: How is it not? It's just a ternary operator. I been using the exact same operator to define `cif`: `ffi_prep_cif(&cif, ABI, args_n, strcmp(ret_t, "int") == 0 ? &ffi_type_sint : strcmp(ret_t, "float") == 0 ? &ffi_type_float : &ffi_type_schar`.

Comment: Okay, so the ternary operator can not return a type at run time, right? Is there a way to iterate over variadic function arguments?

Comment: It's `expression ? expression : expression`. A type is not an expression. Types can't be passed around at runtime, no.

Comment: You might have more luck using C++ and vararg templates.

Comment: I need this to work in C99 or C11. I might try passing `ffi_type` instead of plain C types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use the ternary operator to select a type.  That is invalid syntax, as it can only be used to select an expression.

You'll need to check for each individual type name, and based on that call `va_arg` with the appropriate type argument.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ARG_N; ++i) {
    char *arg = args_types[i];
    if (!strcmp(arg, "int")) {
        args_values[i] = (void *)va_arg(args, int);
    } else if (!strcmp(arg, "float")) {
        args_values[i] = (void *)va_arg(args, float);
    } else {
        args_values[i] = (void *)va_arg(args, char);
    }
  }
```

Even after fixing this, you still have a problem because in one case you're attempting to convert a `float` to a `void *`.  Converting between a floating point type and a pointer type, event with a cast, is not allowed.  You also have a problem with passing in `char` and `float` types, as expressions of these types will be promoted to `int` and `double` respectively and can therefore never be seen in variadic arguments.

To fix this, you'll probably need to dynamically allocate space for each value and assign the pointer to that dynamically allocated space, and look for `int` and `double` instead of `char` and `float`:

```
char *args_types[ARG_N] = {"int", "double", "int"};

...

  for (int i = 0; i < ARG_N; ++i) {
    char *arg = args_types[i];
    if (!strcmp(arg, "int")) {
        int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p = va_arg(args, int);
        args_values[i] = p;
    } else if (!strcmp(arg, "double")) {
        double *p = malloc(sizeof(double));
        *p = va_arg(args, float);
        args_values[i] = p;
    }
  }
```

This also means you'll need to know the types of these values elsewhere to cast the pointers to the proper types, and you'll need to deallocate the space when you're done with it.

Comment: If I attempt to allocate a `char` or a `float` using the example you provided, I encounter an `illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)` error.

Comment: @siery Then you did something else wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same as the code you added after edit: https://paste.debian.net/1298785/.

Comment: I had to unaccept this answer as this basicaly gives me an illegal hardware instruction (core dumped).

Comment: @siery Updated.  The types `char` and `float` can't be passed as variadic arguments.  Also, the use of `...` without any other arguments is not allowed in C99 and C11 mode, only C23 mode.

Comment: I think it is allowed in GCC though.

Comment: How about a `union`? 
    `typedef union { int int_arg; char char_arg; double double_arg; } arg_union ;`

Comment: @dbush Right, it works for `int` and `double`. Thank you for the update.